# Setting up the default AspNetSqlProvider to point to remote database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

When starting a new project that required the use of membership providers I found that I could not connect to a remote database that contained the membership database.

I ran aspnet_regsql and was able to create the membership database on the remote server but when I go to ASPNET Configuration (cassini development server) it will not connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After much searching I found that the default Membership Provider specified in machine.config (c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG) was always pointing to a SQL Server running on the localhost.

Instead of modifying machine.config there is a way to set it up in the projects web.config:

1) Setup the connection string to the remote database

```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="aspnet_membership" connectionString="<your_connection_string>"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

2) In `<system.web>` redefine the default provider:

```
  <membership>
    <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
            connectionStringName="aspnet_membership"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
            applicationName="/" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            passwordFormat="Hashed" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

The `<remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>` is key! All the other key/values were taken directly from machine.config

Comment: You jdiaz, are THE MAN!  I've been stuck on trying to get this working on my non-default SQLExpress instance for hours.  Works great now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Stumbled onto this today. The command `<clear />` is already included in my `<membership.providers>` section. So, I am good?

Answer (score 2):

```
<membership>
       <providers>
           <clear/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
               connectionStringName="aspnet_membership"
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
               enablePasswordReset="true"
               requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
               applicationName="/"
               requiresUniqueEmail="false"
               passwordFormat="Hashed"
               maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
               minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
               minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
               passwordAttemptWindow="10"
               passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
       </providers>
   </membership>
```

I needed to add this lines to get my Roles and Profile staff based on Membership class working:

```
   <profile>
       <providers>
           <clear/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
           connectionStringName="aspnet_membership"
           applicationName="/"
           type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
       </providers>
   </profile>

   <roleManager enabled="true">
       <providers>
           <clear/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
           connectionStringName="aspnet_membership"
           applicationName="/"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
           <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
           applicationName="/"
           type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
       </providers>
   </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

step 2: copy this:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=VMK\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=commodity_exchange;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

step 1:  Launch Visual Studio command prompt
Type: aspnet_regsql
Specify your server: if sqlexpress then server = hostname\sqlexpress
*********************Use Windows Authentication

step 2: Copy this to web config.Dont specify username or password because ur connecting with windows authentication that’s why we have integrated security =true.

step 3 : Change security>Authentication type on web administration tool to "From the Internet".

Enjoy now.