# Oracle Membership

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I'm trying to implement membership with oracle. I have created the database perfectly, but I can not access from my App. The database is on a dadicated server, and the error that its shows me is "OracleConnection.ConnectionString is invalid" but I know that is correct.
I have used this connection with ADO.NET and I works perfectly.
Can I use a remote server to implement membership? because this is the only explinantion that I could find...
This is my connectionstring.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this post: 
[Setting up the default AspNetSqlProvider to point to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345559/setting-up-the-default-aspnetsqlprovider-to-point-to-remote-database)

So my web.config looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=EUBEWD92Z1.jnj.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE))); user id=user; password=pass;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <remove name="OracleMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="OracleMembershipProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        applicationName="/"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        passwordFormat="Hashed"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```