# How can I change the Data Source of Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, provider

I'm setting up Membership on my ASP.Net website.
I'm using a remote database.
I have created membership tables on this database by using aspnet_regsql.exe.

When I click security, I get this error on ASP.Net Web Application
[image: ASP.Net Web Application error]

I clicked Choose Data Source, but there is not an option to be able to set my remote database. What I'm missing ?

How I can fix this error ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Okey I found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345559/setting-up-the-default-aspnetsqlprovider-to-point-to-remote-database)

The machine.config was pointing to my local database,
and I changed my web.config